Django mysql queries slow, direct mysql client queries usually fast
I'm having an issue with slowness in my Django project caused by slow mysql queries.  Cut and paste the query from the Django log, execute it via the mysql client (to the same database, from same server project is on) and usually they are quite fast.
So say regularly 5 secs from DJango .20 seconds via mysql client (again to same db, from same server) typical result.
Sometimes I will see it slow from mysql client, usually the first time it's tried if it's going to happen.  I can try it again even 20 minutes later and it will still be fast typically.
Say it just executed fast via mysql client, if I immediately execute it via the problem Django http request, it will still be slow.

Debug is off for Django.
I can reproduce this problem across mysql server versions.
Production server and database are under very light use and have good
resources available.
I've tried totally recreating the database same issue.
I tried using django-db-connection-pool with no effect.
I've tried profiling and stepping into the code to make sure it's the
query, it is.
Slow query log is not showing these problem queries, though I'm not
sure how it's configured.

any suggestions? cheers

It is not that strange that the second time you perform the same query, it is much faster: often part of the data that was loaded is then still in cache, and so the second time it runs, it only requires some computations, not much data fetching anymore. So SELECT COUNT(*) FROM some_table WHERE some_condition; for example the first time can be quite slow, whereas a second time, a lot of records might still be in memory, boosting performance enourmously.

Yeh I get that but we we see is ALWAYS slow from Django.  So it doesn't matter if I were to execute on mysql client first for example.  Also when we do see it slow on mysql client, it doesn't seem to matter if Django side ran first or not.  So I don't think there's much correlation.  So the problem remains why always slow via Django.

"Cut and paste the query from the Django log, execute it via the mysql client (to the same database, from same server project is on) and usually they are quite fast" ... seems like we have to call out this "usually" in your statement. If it isn't always fast, it isn't always fast. That means its not a fast query that django runs slowly, its a query that is sometimes fast and sometimes slow. What about this query? What does it do? What is it?

Would you consider posting one query that is SLOW and the SHOW CREATE TABLE (tbl_names) for each table referenced? Maybe we can tell you why, after analysis of this information.

Could you post your Django client configuration information?
